# html display as plain text in backend order details shipping method fieldset

Tags: magento-1.9, fieldsets

Here is the code which will override default sales model order to display additional info in shipping information fieldset

```
<?php
class Custom_Test_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{
    public function getShippingDescription(){
        $desc = parent::getShippingDescription();
        $pickupObject = $this->getPickupObject();
        if($pickupObject){
            $desc .= "<br><b>Store</b>: ".$pickupObject->getStore();
            $desc .= "<br><b>Name</b>: ".$pickupObject->getName();
            $desc .= "<br>";
        }
        return $desc;
    }
}
```

but all the html 
 are displaying in plaintext, anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try using html_entity_decode()

```
<?php
class Custom_Test_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{
    public function getShippingDescription(){
        $desc = parent::getShippingDescription();
        $pickupObject = $this->getPickupObject();
        if($pickupObject){
            $desc .= "<br><b>Store</b>: ".$pickupObject->getStore();
            $desc .= "<br><b>Name</b>: ".$pickupObject->getName();
            $desc .= "<br>";
        }
        return html_entity_decode($desc);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not work